# Permission Requests causes infinite loop in OnResume

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

In API >= 23, we are required to ask users for permission at run-time. But for some reason, the permissions are causing onResume to be called infinitely. What causes this?

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
     new String[]{Manifest.permission.ANYPERMISSION},1);       

}

 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
     }
```

Comment: You better ask for permission in onCreate().

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you show dialog of permission question, Acitvity goes to `onPause`, and when dialog hides, it goes to `onResume`. You have to change place of asking of permission.

Comment: Ahh, was not aware dialogue makes it go to `onPause`

Comment: Check as answered if I helped you ;)

Comment: I will as soon as the timer lets me. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

A small piece of code for permissions to complete previous response :)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        ensurePermissions(
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
}
```

and:

```
@TargetApi(23)
private void ensurePermissions(String... permissions) {
    boolean request = false;
    for (String permission : permissions)
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            request = true;
            break;
        }

    if (request) {
        requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

Comment: checking in onCreate is wrong; first - activity could have not be shown at all (onstart, onresume never called); second - what if user grants permission in oncreate then goes out of app then chenges permission then returns to app?

Answer (score 0):

first, your app needs to check whether you have been granted a particular permission before asking runtime permission.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```