# Why might all activities get closed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm facing a very strange error where all activities in my app are getting closed when interacting (touching or scrolling) with the app.

I've tried setting breakpoints on `onActivityStopped()` and `onStop()` callbacks and they do get called but I can't see where or how this process is getting started.

There is nothing showing in the logs that leads me to think there has been an exeception or anything strange.

Any idea why this might be happening and how to debug it?

Comment: Logcat share please.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya done

Comment: And you're not getting any error messages (like "Activity has stopped working")? Also the logcat you posted is not useful, look for exception stacktraces instead.

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm not getting any errors with exception stacktraces or anything. It's just that all the activities are getting closed and I don't know where or how it's originating.

Comment: That's strange, never experienced that. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It could be that log _is_ shown but it gets filtered away from your logcat. I suggest using a third party tool or reset your Android Studio

Comment: @m0skit0 It's happening inside this app I'm working on. I have no idea what part of the whole code is causing this, so it'd be really hard for me to provide that.

Comment: @FranSevillano Try creating an MCVE anyway. "By identifying more clearly where the problem occurs, you have just made an important step toward solving it. The process that highlights where a problem originates can, in itself, help to solve it. You might look more closely at the part cut out, and in doing so, spot the problem" ([source](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @FranSevillano the **Android OS** rarely kills activities that are in the foreground (displayed to the user and the user is interacting with). All other activities in your app are fair game if the the **Android OS** is hungry for resources e.g. memory etc. If things are happening as you claim then your app is the least of your worries there could be something wrong with your emulator. Try another emulator or another physical device. P.S. Share your logs the community might help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue. Starting location updates from the `onResume()` method was resulting on the activity being paused and then resumed ad-infinitum when locations services were disabled.

What I think was happening was:

- Location permissions were requested from the activity's `onResume()` method.
- Doing so causes `onPause()` to be called on the activity when the location dialog is supposed to be shown, even know it isn't anymore because we already denied them.
- Then `onResume()` is called and the cycle perpetuates itself.

At some point if you interacted with the activity at all, they system would close it (along with the others) for some reason I don't fully understand.

I think the TL;DR is: *avoid starting location services from `onResume()`*.

Some seemingly related issues: [Permission Requests causes infinite loop in OnResume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680921/permission-requests-causes-infinite-loop-in-onresume) and https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher/issues/90